# Drupal 8 set cookie on every page load using event subscriber

Tags: php, cookies, drupal-8

I am trying to set a cookie on every page load. I did some research and found that event subscribers are the way to go.
I created a custom module with event. It starts the event on every page load but the problem is with the cookies.

The $event object has property called response but it is always null.
Therefore i cannot set any cookies.

```
 class LanguageCookieSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface 
 {

    protected $event;

    protected $cookieValue;

    public function init(GetResponseEvent $event) {

      $this->event = $event;

      $cookie = new Cookie("client_language_cookie", $this->cookieValue, 0, '/', NULL, FALSE);

      $this->event->getResponse()->headers->setCookie($cookie);
   }
 }
```

I also tried to set the response object. Then I can set the cookie but the page will come blank.

```
  $response = new Response();
  $this->event->setResponse($response);
  $cookie = new Cookie("client_language_cookie", $this->cookieValue, 0, '/', NULL, FALSE);
  $this->event->getResponse()->headers->setCookie($cookie);
```

Any ideas how can i solve this? I need to display the page user has requested and only set cookie.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem right now, I'm still working on it. But probably you are subscribing  `kernel.request` event? On kernel.request, there are no response object yet, probably try subscribe on kernel.response

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
  public function onKernelResponse(ResponseEvent $event) {
    $response = $event->getResponse();

     $cookie = new Cookie('cookie name', 'my_cookie value', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
     $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
     $event->setResponse($response);
  }
```